# Accidentally send NFT to a ETH coinbase direction

Tags: nft

I send an NFT from a Metamask Wallet to one of my ETH addresses on Coinbase. Actually, if I access Opensea using that direction on the mobile app I can see the NFT. How can I recover it or send it back? because i can't see it thru Coinbase (Web) or Wallet

Comment: Can you share the transaction hash? When you say Coinbase do you mean the mobile application or the exchange? If it is the exchange you have to ask their customer support for help.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Coinbase support
https://help.coinbase.com/en/contact-us?

Coinbase do not provide such features I think.

use metamask or any browser wallet for such things, which give you access to your `private key`.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue. Coinbase was not able to help. So I can vue nft on some account on opensea that has my wallet address but I can't access it. It's like it created a generic account I can't access